# How to embed javascript code dynamically into HTML

Tags: javascript

We have a requirement, where a javascript needs to be rendered dynamically when the HTML page is rendered. The javascript function could be used to draw a circle or triangle or a square. Assuming the following code snippet is stored in a certain field in the database, how do you embed such code directly into HTML at a certain location.

```
<script src="../js/processing.js"></script>
<script src="../js/shapes.js"></script>

<div style="clear:both;"/>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script id="script1" type="text/javascript">
var sketch = new Processing.Sketch();
sketch.attachFunction = function(processing) {
processing.setup = setup(processing);
processing.draw = drawCircle(processing);
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var p = new Processing(canvas, sketch);
</script>
```

Comment: Which server platform are you using? Are you wanting the script to be inserted when the server builds the page or are you wanting the client to perform an async postback to get the script and execute it?

Comment: this should happen when server builds the page not on a async postback

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy using AJAX. Obtain the script snippet using AJAX and then place it in a script tag in your body, it should execute :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can easily be done but way is vary as per server technology.

like in Ruby on Rails:

let assume your script is stored in some ruby variable say js_script as

```
 js_script = 'var sketch = new Processing.Sketch();
 sketch.attachFunction = function(processing) {
 processing.setup = setup(processing);
 processing.draw = drawCircle(processing);
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var p = new Processing(canvas, sketch);'
```

Following code will work in your HTML file

```
<script id="script1" type="text/javascript">


<%= js_script -%> #  here the magic happens, it replaced this block with js_script 


</script>
```

Note:In order to execute dynamic script properly, you should load all required elements and js files before calling it.

Like in your case you should call it after creating canvas1 element because it is required in your script